# Clickable hyperlink with \overset and XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, hyperref, amsmath

I would like my document to have clickable hyperlinks inside `\overset` environments. I'm using XeLaTeX because of the fonts…

This is a (rather) minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[xetex, colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    a = b \label{eq} \tag{$\ast$}
\end{equation}

\[ \eqref{eq} \] % working hyperlink here.

\[ c = a \overset{\eqref{eq}}{=} b \] % existing but non-clickable hyperlink here.

\end{document}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436), and thanks for providing a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).  Interesting that it works fine with `pfdLaTeX`, but not `XeLaTeX`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks for pointing that out! I tried to compile my document with LuaLaTeX and amazingly it simply worked and showed the correct hyperlinks! While this doesn't explain the behaviour of XeLaTeX, it's a simpler workaround than I could have dreamed of! Cheers!

Comment: If you use `(\ref{eq})` rather than `\eqref{eq}` it will work, even with xelatex

Comment: Unravelling the definitions of `\overset` and `\eqref`, the problem appears minimally with `$\text{\ref{eq}}$`, provided `amstext` is used.

Comment: The problem occurs any time you have `\text{\ref{eq}}` in a math size other than `\displaystyle`.  So in display math mode you need a superscript to produce the problem (`\overset` implicitly creates a superscript, and `\eqref` uses the `\textup` command that unravels to `\text`), but in inline math the problem occurs without a superscript.

Comment: `$ c = a \overset{\mbox{\scriptsize\eqref{eq}}}{=} b $` works.

Comment: @user700902 Can you make an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a workaround for XeLaTeX as pointed out by @user700902:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[xetex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    a = b \label{eq} \tag{$\ast$}
\end{equation}

\[ c  = a \overset{\mbox{\scriptsize\eqref{eq}}}{=} b\] % thanks user700902 

\end{document}
```

I however chose to use LuaLaTeX, which didn't require any change of the source code.