# No hyperref link in stackrel with xelatex

Tags: xetex, hyperref, cross-referencing

Consider the following example document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:eq1}
    a = b\quad \wedge \quad b = c
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \text{\eqref{eq:eq1}} \Rightarrow a = c
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    a \stackrel{\text{\eqref{eq:eq1}}}{=} c
\end{equation}

From \eqref{eq:eq1} we know that $a = c$.

\end{document}
```

There are 3 occurences of `\eqref`. With `pdflatex` all of them create links to the first equation, but with `xelatex` for the second occurence (inside `\stackrel`) only the label text is printed while no hyperlink is created in the resulting `pdf` file.

How does this come about and what are possible solutions?

Comment: Curious. The font used by `\stackrel` (`\overset` is better, however) is `\scriptsize`, not `\tiny`.

Comment: Seems the problem was known for `\overset`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99944/clickable-hyperlink-with-overset-and-xelatex . I'm not sure whether to close this question as duplicate and submit a bug report for xetex, or rather leave it, as I'm also asking for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

An immediate work-around is to leave out the `amsmath` command `\text`. Instead one can use `\mbox`. The following works in `xelatex`:

```
\begin{equation}
    a \stackrel{\mbox{\normalfont\tiny\eqref{eq:eq1}}}{=} c
\end{equation}
```